# Iterating over llvm::Function to get pass result

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to perform some analysis on llvm IR. For this I try to get the result of the MemorySSAAnalysis pass in each function of a IR module.

However when analyzing the second function, a crash occurs:

```
  Successfully read Module:
  Name: /mnt/DATA/LLVM/llvm-project/build_dyn_debug/sample1_O3.ll
  Target triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Invalidating analysis: InnerAnalysisManagerProxy<llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>, llvm::Module> on /mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/build_dyn_debug/sample1_O3.ll
  Invalidating analysis: LazyValueAnalysis on test
  Invalidating analysis: LazyValueAnalysis on test
  Invalidating analysis: LazyValueAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: MemorySSAAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: LazyValueAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: LoopAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: PhiValuesAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: MemoryDependenceAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: DemandedBitsAnalysis on main
  Invalidating analysis: CallGraphAnalysis on /mnt/DATA/LLVM/llvm-project/build_dyn_debug/sample1_O3.ll
  ; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind uwtable
  define dso_local void @test(i32 %a) local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !20 {
  entry:
    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 %a, metadata !25, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !26
    %cmp = icmp sgt i32 %a, 0, !dbg !27
    br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.end, !dbg !29

    if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
    ; 1 = MemoryDef(liveOnEntry)
    %puts = tail call i32 @puts(i8* nonnull dereferenceable(1) getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @str, i64 0, i64 0)), !dbg !30
    br label %if.end, !dbg !32

    if.end:                                           ; preds = %if.then, %entry
    ; 2 = MemoryPhi({entry,liveOnEntry},{if.then,1})
      ret void, !dbg !33
  }
  test: /mnt/DATA/LLVM/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ilist_iterator.h:138:llvm::ilist_iterator<OptionsT, IsReverse, IsConst>::reference llvm::ilist_iterator<OptionsT, IsReverse, IsConst>::operator*() const [with OptionsT = llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::BasicBlock, true, false, void>; bool IsReverse = false; bool IsConst = false; llvm::ilist_iterator<OptionsT, IsReverse, IsConst>::reference = llvm::BasicBlock&]: Assertion `!NodePtr->isKnownSentinel()' failed.
  Abandon (core dumped)
```

[EDIT] Here is the stack trace

```
  libc.so.6!__GI_raise(int sig) (/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50)
  libc.so.6!__GI_abort() (/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/stdlib/abort.c:79)
  libc.so.6!__assert_fail_base(const char * fmt, const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) (/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/assert/assert.c:92)
  libc.so.6!__GI___assert_fail(const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) (/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/assert/assert.c:101)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::BasicBlock, true, false, void>, false, false>::operator*(const llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::BasicBlock, true, false, void>,false, false> * const this) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ilist_iterator.h:138)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::simple_ilist<llvm::BasicBlock>::front(llvm::simple_ilist<llvm::BasicBlock> * const this) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/simple_ilist.h:138)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::Function::front(llvm::Function * const this) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:772)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::Function::getEntryBlock(llvm::Function * const this) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Function.h:749)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::GraphTraits<llvm::Function*>::getEntryNode(llvm::Function * F) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/CFG.h:350)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DomTreeBuilder::SemiNCAInfo<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >::GetEntryNode(const llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> & DT) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/GenericDomTreeConstruction.h:344)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DomTreeBuilder::SemiNCAInfo<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >::FindRoots(const llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> & DT, llvm::DomTreeBuilder::SemiNCAInfo<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >::BatchUpdatePtr BUI) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/GenericDomTreeConstruction.h:356)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DomTreeBuilder::SemiNCAInfo<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >::CalculateFromScratch(llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> & DT, llvm::DomTreeBuilder::SemiNCAInfo<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >::BatchUpdatePtr BUI) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/GenericDomTreeConstruction.h:578)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DomTreeBuilder::Calculate<llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> >(llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> & DT) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/GenericDomTreeConstruction.h:1563)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false>::recalculate(llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false> * const this, llvm::DominatorTreeBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false>::ParentType & Func) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/Support/GenericDomTree.h:780)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::DominatorTreeAnalysis::run(llvm::DominatorTreeAnalysis * const this, llvm::Function & F) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/lib/IR/Dominators.cpp:363)
  libLLVMPasses.so.13git!llvm::detail::AnalysisPassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::DominatorTreeAnalysis, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::Invalidator>::run(llvm::detail::AnalysisPassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::DominatorTreeAnalysis, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::Invalidator> * const this, llvm::Function & IR, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> & AM) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:315)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::getResultImpl(llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> * const this, llvm::AnalysisKey * ID, llvm::Function & IR) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerImpl.h:75)
  libLLVMAnalysis.so.13git!llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::getResult<llvm::DominatorTreeAnalysis>(llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> * const this, llvm::Function & IR) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:788)
  libLLVMAnalysis.so.13git!llvm::MemorySSAAnalysis::run(llvm::MemorySSAAnalysis * const this, llvm::Function & F, llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager & AM) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Analysis/MemorySSA.cpp:2329)
  libLLVMPasses.so.13git!llvm::detail::AnalysisPassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::MemorySSAAnalysis, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::Invalidator>::run(llvm::detail::AnalysisPassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::MemorySSAAnalysis, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::Invalidator> * const this, llvm::Function & IR, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> & AM) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:315)
  libLLVMCore.so.13git!llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::getResultImpl(llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> * const this, llvm::AnalysisKey * ID, llvm::Function & IR) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerImpl.h:75)
  llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>::getResult<llvm::MemorySSAAnalysis>(llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> * const this, llvm::Function & IR) (/mnt/DATA/LLVM12/install_dyn_debug/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:788)
  main(int argc, char ** argv) (/mnt/DATA/Merce/project/erlvaltic/clang/tool/main.cpp:380)
```

[/EDIT]

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"   
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include "llvm/Passes/PassBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Analysis/MemorySSA.h"
using namespace llvm;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " ll_filename" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  StringRef filename = argv[1];

  LLVMContext Context;
  SMDiagnostic Err;
  auto m = parseIRFile(filename, Err, Context);
  if (m) {
    std::cout << "Successfully read Module:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Name: " << m->getName().str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Target triple: " << m->getTargetTriple() << std::endl;

    llvm::PassBuilder passBuilder;
    llvm::LoopAnalysisManager loopAnalysisManager(true); // true is just to output debug info
    llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager functionAnalysisManager(true);
    llvm::CGSCCAnalysisManager cGSCCAnalysisManager(true);
    llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager moduleAnalysisManager(true);

    passBuilder.registerModuleAnalyses(moduleAnalysisManager);
    passBuilder.registerCGSCCAnalyses(cGSCCAnalysisManager);
    passBuilder.registerFunctionAnalyses(functionAnalysisManager);
    passBuilder.registerLoopAnalyses(loopAnalysisManager);
   
    passBuilder.crossRegisterProxies(
        loopAnalysisManager, functionAnalysisManager, cGSCCAnalysisManager, moduleAnalysisManager);
        llvm::ModulePassManager modulePassManager =
    passBuilder.buildPerModuleDefaultPipeline(llvm::PassBuilder::OptimizationLevel::O3);
    modulePassManager.run(*m, moduleAnalysisManager);

    FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM =
        moduleAnalysisManager.getResult<FunctionAnalysisManagerModuleProxy>(*m).getManager();
    auto &functionList = m->getFunctionList();
    for (auto &function : functionList) {
        auto &MSSA = FAM.getResult<MemorySSAAnalysis>(function).getMSSA();
        MSSA.dump();
    }   
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Error while reading module" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Any help on what happens and how to solve this ?
Why analysis are invalidated ?

Thanks

[EDIT2]
It seems that the issue is related to some debug info in my IR file. The second function on which the core dump occured was :

```
  ; Function Attrs: nofree nosync nounwind readnone speculatable willreturn
  declare void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata, metadata, metadata) #1
```

[/EDIT2]

Comment: Analyses are invalidated because the function does. For example, if an optimising pass removes a loop. it has to invalidate the LoopInfo analysis. For the rest, usual debugging comments apply. Build with debugging, use the verifier, use valgrind. I'm astonished by how many questions here could be avoided using those tools. [This, for example,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67720244) would be solved using the same debugging techniques as you need.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for your answer. And I agree with you. I do use the debugger and also have the llvm framework compiled in debug mode. The stack trace is not given at the end of the execution and I should have given the one of my IDE. I will edit my message.

Comment: Uhm... I have a feeling that you're not getting the full value of your debug build. LLVM is full of assert() calls and you tend to hit an assert() long before you get a segfault. The last like of my compile-a-single-function function reads `assert(!verifyFunction(*getFunction(), &llvm::errs()));` and that's caught a lot of bugs early. I suggest that you check that a failed assert() stops your compile right away.

Comment: Thanks @arnt . In my original message, before the core dump, there is a failed assert. The line is very long but ends with "Assertion `!NodePtr->isKnownSentinel()' failed." I also added the verifyFunction and my first failed assert is the same as previously

Comment: Ok I understood the issue : my IR file contained debug info.  The core dump occured on a function declare related to those debug info. I will edit the message. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was not an issue with the code but with the input data which had debug info (see EDIT2 in the question)